# Ice4j: Testing IcePseudoTcp - STUN server needed?

Tags: java, nat, stun, nat-traversal, ice4j

Does anyone know the process of testing IcePseduoTcp? Is it self contained, or do you have to point it to a STUN server for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code states:

```
        StunCandidateHarvester stunHarv = new StunCandidateHarvester(
            new TransportAddress("sip-communicator.net",
                                 3478, Transport.UDP));
        StunCandidateHarvester stun6Harv = new StunCandidateHarvester(
            new TransportAddress("ipv6.sip-communicator.net",
                                 3478, Transport.UDP));
```

So you don't need your own STUN server it points to one.

Comment: I am not sure sim-commnicator is reachable, so perhaps you might want to add your own stuncandidateharvester. You can try: "stun.iptel.org" with the same code I posted.

Comment: any idea / recommendation for a library, that will let me develop a turn client, i am looking to use turn protocol (for proxying purpose) without ice